# How to determine if DWG was made in foreign program

Tags: autocad, dwg

I'm currently developing a solution that utilizes Open Design Alliance to read DWG files. I'm trying to implement a similar feature that exists in the AutoCad program itself -- AutoCad will notify the user if the file's origin is not from a licensed AutoCad application. ([See Here](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Open-foreign-DWG-file-message-appears-in-AutoCAD.html))

I have explored the library in depth and have concluded that the information I need to determine this is most likely available but I'm having a hard time figuring out what the guidelines are that signify the file is from AutoCad origin, or not. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any existing guidelines, but if I would to do that, I would attach some XData (timestamp for example) to Modelspace or some dictionary each time user click `Save`. When drawing will be saved on other application there will be no such data, or data (timestamp) will be not corresponding to last save time of drawing.